# getting a output in javascript to show as a link

Tags: javascript

I have been having troubles how I can get email and website outputs in my `var message` to show as hyperlinks using the `<a>` tag. I have the code below any help would be appreciated.

```
function process() {

    // VARIABLES
    var faculty  = document.getElementById("faculty").value;
    var staff = document.getElementById("staff").value;
    var dr = document.getElementById("dr").value;
    var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var cert = document.getElementById("cert").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var department = document.getElementById("department").value;
    var tel1 = document.getElementById("tel1").value;
    var tel2 = document.getElementById("tel2").value;
    var tel3 = document.getElementById("tel3").value;
    var website = document.getElementById("website").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");



    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    // Create a new object:
    var employee = {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        cert: cert,
        title: title,
        department: department,
        email: email,
        phone: tel1 + tel2 + tel3,
        website: website,
    };

    console.log(employee);

    // Create the ouptut as HTML:
    var message = "<h2>Directory:</h2>" + employee.first_name + ", " + employee.last_name + "&nbsp;" + employee.cert + "<br>";
    message += employee.title + "<br>";
    message += employee.department + "<br>";
    message += employee.email +"<br>";
    message += "Phone: " + employee.phone + "<br>";
    message += "Website:" + employee.website + "<br>";


    // Display the employee object:
    output.innerHTML = message;

    // Return false:
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Java programming tag removed -- your question looks to have nothing to do with this programming language. If I deleted this in error, please comment back and explain why you think so.

Comment: `message += "Website: <a href='" + employee.website + "'>" + employee.website + "</a><br>";`

Comment: You're constructing the HTML as text. Just construct your `message` string as text the way the HTML should look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a message as a link you can do:

```
message += "<a href='/"+ employee.title +"'>"+ employee.title +"</a><br>";
```

similar way to any other element

Comment: thank you Marcin C. that makes a lot more sense compared to what i was trying to do ....of just slapping the employee. between a < a href> tag i appreciate the help

Comment: Not a  problem at all :)